# How to pass c_char_p in c struct into CDLL exported function

Tags: python, c, ctypes, dllimport

A have some function imported from dll: foo

For simplicity, function "foo" does next things:

```
# c code
struct bar {
    char *s1;
    char *s2;
};

int foo(struct bar *aBarPtr)
{
    if (NULL != aBarPtr) {
        aBarPtr->s1 = "Some static string";
        aBarPtr->s2 = "Some static string2";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In Python i create structure:

```
# Python code
class BAR(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("s1", c_char_p),
        ("s2", c_char_p)
    ]
```

And call function:

```
# Python code
FOO = my_dll_handle.foo
FOO.argtypes = [POINTER(BAR)]
bar_elem = BAR(c_char_p(), c_char_p())
retcode = FOO(byref(bar_elem))
```

But after call, s1 and s2 in bar_elem point to None, but not to some strings from DLLs.

How to fix it?

Comment: It's best to publish a working example that exhibits the problem.  but with minor changes the code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absent a few lines to get the code to compile and run, it works:

#### X.DLL

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#endif

struct bar {
    char *s1;
    char *s2;
};

EXPORT int foo(struct bar *aBarPtr)
{
    if (aBarPtr) {
        aBarPtr->s1 = "Some static string";
        aBarPtr->s2 = "Some static string2";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### Python

```
from ctypes import *
class BAR(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("s1", c_char_p),
        ("s2", c_char_p)
    ]

foo = CDLL('x').foo
foo.argtypes = [POINTER(BAR)]
bar = BAR()
print(foo(byref(bar)))
print(bar.s1)
print(bar.s2)
```

#### Output

```
0
b'Some static string'
b'Some static string2'
```